# Retrieve a git repository on windows, can't use "keychain"

Tags: windows, git, ssh

my client sent me two keygen files (one is public and the other is private) and asked me to follow these steps to get their source:

> $ vim .ssh/config  # create a ssh config
>
> Host git.xxx.com
>
> IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys/yourSource
>
> $ keychain ~/.ssh/keys/yourSource   # load the private key with keychain
>
> $ git clone git@git.yourSource.com:something.git
>
> $ cd something

I've put the keygen files they sent me in ~/.ssh/keys. I gave them my public key and they said they'd set it up.

But I have problems after creating the config file. I wasn't allowed to use "keychain" command on windows platform. (Git bash displays "command not found".) Is there any way else I can load the private key?

Comment: Are you sure you need it? Keychains seem to be a Mac thing. What happens if you skip the `keychain` command?

Comment: Hi musiKk, Yes I know it's a Mac thing. But if I skip this command I won't be allowed to access the git resource.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you need the keychain command. This one is used on Unix environments (Linux/Mac) only.

What you need on Windows is this setup:

- in your c:\Users\.ssh folder, have two key files (default names id_rsa and id_rsa.pub). Use those provided or generate some with ssh-keygen
- provide the contents of the public key to your client for setup with git repository
- test the setup with git clone.

It is a bit strange that the client has provided you with both private and public keys rather than asking you to generate your own. The whole purpose of the public/private keys in security is to ensure that the private remains private so that the identity of one user/commiter can't be duplicated. If they have your private key then someone might (even accidentally) use your identity to access the git repository.